# How to phase fold data when periodicity change is known as d$\omega$/d$t$?

Tags: radial-velocity, eclipsing-star-systems

How can I obtain a phase-folded phase - velocity diagramme from a time series of radial velocity data when it is known that the periodicity changes as $\frac{{d}\omega}{{d}t}$?

Without $\frac{{d}\omega}{{d}t}$ it is:

```
p = ((T-Tref)/P)%1.0
```

$T$ is a time

$T_{ref}$ is a reference time

$P$ is a period

$p$ is fold phase

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to SE. I think your question would profit if you could at least briefly explain your notation. IMHO a bit more context would not hurt either (what do you mean with 'phase'? Do you mean 'phase fold'?)

Comment: Yes, I mean phase fold.

Comment: I made another edit in which I tried to capture the uniqueness here that the change in periodicity is the crucial point. Please revert or change, if my edit changes your question in a bad way.

Comment: It would also improve the question if you told us what you tried and what sources you checked for a solution yourself. Had you tried to create a new time base to a t' = $ t / d\omega/dt$ or converting time directly into omega as you know the relation $t(\omega)$ - and do the phase-folding only as last step once you have a amplitude - omega relation (which is not yet folded)

Comment: Using your formula, what is t'? It would be incredibly large and the units do not correspond.

Comment: t is time. If you have RV data, you have a date and time attached to your measurements. Yes, t is large, but the offset is arbitrary and does not matter. That's why you often see in these time plots time denoted as JD-2415743 or similar. Similar it does not matter if $\omega$ is offset by a huge multiple of $2\pi$ (or 360°).

Comment: Thanks and do you have a reference for this relation.

Comment: Uhm... I'm suggesting only a simple coordinate transform from $t$ (you call it $T$) to $\omega$. This assumes that you know your period $P$ - but that is required anyway when you want to phase-fold your data. And tbh, it doesn't matter at which time of the phase you start as long as you cover exactly $2\pi$. The definition of what time equals phase = 0 is completely arbitrary. Mind the relation that period and frequency are related: $P = 2\pi/\omega$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\omega(t)$ is
$$ \omega(t) = \omega(T_0) + \int_{T_0}^{t} \frac{d\omega}{dt}\ dt$$
then the phase $\phi(t)$ is
$$ \phi(t) = \phi(T_0) + \int_{T_0}^{t} \omega(t)\ dt$$

And your phase-folded ($0 \rightarrow 1$)) coordinate would be
$$p = \left(\frac{\phi(t) - \phi(T_0)}{2\pi}\right) - {\rm floor}\left(\frac{\phi(t) - \phi(T_0)}{2\pi}\right)\ ,   $$
where floor truncates a decimal to an integer.